# which Force does ball experience when we throw it directly upward Newton's third law or Gravity?

Tags: gravity, newtonian-gravity

As we all aware of Newton's third law that every action there is equal and opposite reaction. And we also know that gravity pull everything toward itself. So gravity or Newton's third law, which is acting on ball when we throw it straight upward.

Answer (score 1):

Newton's third law isn't a Force, it's a condition for Forces in classical mechanics. It states that [with some conditions such that they are the same 'type' of force] if there is some Force from one object acting on another, that object imparts an opposite force with the same magnitude.

The forces the *Ball* experiences is just the sum of the force from the hand and the force from the Earth's gravity.

Comment: so is there any difference between the force of the ball when it thrown and when it is just dropped.?

Comment: Yep, when it's thrown [for example, straight upwards] the force exerted on the ball by you is much stronger than Gravity's, so it moves up, but since you've let go of it and gravity hasn't, it constantly does work against the Kinetic energy you've given, and eventually Gravity stops it's motion momentarily, before causing it to accelerate back down to the ground [assuming you can't throw like a missile launcher and it ends up in space]

Comment: but I'm not confirmed that Newton's third law applicable everywhere or not...

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you have two systems:

- the ball
- the thrower and the Earth

In the act of throwing a ball upwards and ignoring air resistance there will be two forces acting on **the ball**:

- an upward contact force due to **the thrower and the Earth**
- a downward gravitational force due to **the thrower and the Earth**

In the act of throwing a ball upwards and ignoring air resistance there will be two forces acting on **the thrower and the Earth**:

- a downward contact force due to **the ball**
- an upward gravitational force due to **the ball**

The pair of contact forces and the pair of gravitational forces are examples of the forces mentioned in Newton's third law - "for every force on body **one** due body **two** there is an equal in magnitude and opposite in direction force on body **two** due to body **one**"

Comment: so what is the total force.?

Comment: @MentalShakya On the ball the net force is the sum of the downward gravitational force and the upward contact force produced by the thrower and the Earth. With the magnitude of the contact force being greater then the gravitational force.

Comment: I thought that there is only gravitational force act on that ball because when we drop a ball from any height from distance (let x) and when we throw the ball directly upward then let it also travel distance x . Now, on both that cases only gravitational force will act.

Comment: @MentalShakya Once there is no contact force, ie the thrower is not touching the ball, then the only force on the ball is the gravitational attraction due to the thrower and the Earth.

Comment: so can we say the total force is only gravitational pull.

Comment: @MentalShakya yes if you ignore air resistance.

Comment: so Newton's third law is not applicable for everywhere.

Comment: @MentalShakya I do not understand your question. Newton's third law is to do with two forces which act on different objects. So the force on the ball due to the gravitational attraction of the Earth has a Newton third law pair which is the force on the Earth due to the gravitational attraction of the ball.

Comment: I m sorry . But Newton's law is not exerting here any force by the way and force is directly proportional to the distance . And if the Newton's law acting here then the ball having both force( gravity as well as force applied by us on ball) and it strike the ground with sum of these forces. But if you do an experiment then you will not find that there are any other force except gravitational force. So finally here Newton's law not applicable.

Comment: you can do experiment by: put one ball at any distance (let it be x) and drop it down. Again throw a ball which speed become zero at this distance (x) . And you get result that both strike ground with same force. So where Newton's third law gone?....

Comment: Newton's Law only stipulates that Force pairs sum to zero. The force of the Ball on the Earth, and the Force of the Earth on the ball sum to zero as they are equal in magnitude but opposite.

Comment: @Phase but it is only when ball dropped to ground. Not in air. But the resultant force of ball on Earth is not sum of gravitational force and contact force.

Comment: Ok please try READING what me and Farcher have written. Newton's Third law only requires that objects, when interacting with each other, exert the same force on each other in opposite directions. When the ball is in the air, it's gravitational acceleration is balanced by the earth gravitating towards the ball.

Comment: You are not going to be debunking any reknowned scientist by arguing from incredulity.

Answer (score 0):

Both. 
1) Gravity
2) The earth also falls towards the ball, providing an equal an opposite reaction.